# Redefining an initialiser declared as NS_UNAVAILABLE by parent class

Tags: objective-c, initialization

I want to redefine an initialiser which was previously declared as `NS_UNAVAILABLE` by the parent class.

Such as:

```
@interface Parent : NSObject

// Unavailable
- (instancetype)init NS_UNAVAILABLE;

// Some other (appropriate) initialiser
- (instancetype)initWithWhatever:(id)whatever NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;

@end
```

It would make sense that any calls to child initialisers need to propagate to the parent's designated initialiser.

Let's say that default arguments make sense on the child class and therefore:

```
@interface Child : Parent

// Propagates to initWithWhatever:
- (instancetype)init NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;

@end
```

Even though the initialiser is redeclared by the child class Xcode seems to still think that it's unavailable. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Say thanks to that guys, who thought a static typing programming language in nowadays is a good idea and destroyed Objective-C. Neither is such a decoration necessary for Objective-C nor does it conform to the basic ideas of Objective-C. However, you need a solution. Since object initialization is nothing special, esp. initialization methods are nothing special, simply change the name of the method. Isn't it a solution for you? Making a method available again in a subclass would cause problems with Liskov. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

Comment: I know it doesn't conform to Objc's concept of initialisers but the fact that some base classes stop making sense with some initialisers (ie., there are no defaults, but an extra argument is required) makes me work around these issues quite often. Objective-c's designers just got it wrong, IMO. I guess I could use a different name, but what? `initWithNothing`? Where would that go after a few levels of inheritance?

Comment: I would agree that the *recent changes* in Objective-C as `NS_UNAVAILABLE` points to the wrong direction., but at least it makes the declaration better in Liskov's meanings. However, obviously `-initWithDefaults` would be an appropriate name for it. Since there is no formal need to add `NS_UNAVAILABLE` for you, you still use `-initWithDefaults` until *you* want to use `NS_UNAVAILABLE`. You are talking about a problem that is easy solvable. (BTW: It is similar to `final` in many programming languages.)

Comment: That's not what I meant at all, but rather that the entire concept of constructor inheritance is wrong. One shouldn't inherit constructors. That fact does not compromise Leskov's substitution principle because that would apply only after an object is constructed (maybe instantiating using reflection is a different issue, but I don't think that should be used either). I don't get it, how is it similar to `final`?

Comment: The concept is not wrong and works better by far in comparison to stack allocating languages. It is similar to `final`, because a base class decision is inherited without a chance to change it in the subclass.

Comment: Why doesn't object construction deal with Liskov?

Comment: I'm not sure I passed the right idea, I don't see how constructor inheritance is related to stack allocation. What I'm saying is that constructors shouldn't be inherited, whatever the way is used for allocation. Liskov doesn't apply to construction because an unconstructed object is not an object. Liskov states that objects are substitutable with objects of child classes, which implies that an **instance** exists. As instances should **always** be properly initialised, substitution is always safe.

Comment: And don't even get me started on this `NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER` thing...

Comment: Yep, you passed some right ideas: 1. The construction is related to stack allocation, because stack allocation has to be done by the compiler / runtime (because it handles the stack) so you need language defined rules for construction. In Objective-C construction can be completely defined outside the language. 2. The messages you send for construction are sent to an object, because in Objective-C classes are objects. Additionally `-init` is sent to an instances. Moreover, you do not fulfill the rule, if something is done "properly", but if it is done in the same way as in the base class.

Comment: Your problem with DI likely has its origin in your misunderstanding of construction and objects in Objective-C.Esp. construction methods are "usual" methods. There is nothing special about them.

Comment: I know that construction is related to stack allocation, what I'm saying is that it's not related to constructor *inheritance*. Somewhere along the discussion these two concepts got mixed up. I know about 2 and that's precisely what I think is wrong in Objc: uninitialised objects shouldn't exist. The fact that initialisers are just usual methods is what got us to this discussion in the first place. In Objc they are but they shouldn't be, it's been my whole point from the start. I understand, I believe, I just don't think it's correct. Maybe it's just my C++ background kicking in, who knows.

Comment: About classes being objects, as I mentioned reflection would be a different topic. I'm talking about compiler enforced construction here, whether using the stack or the heap.

Comment: I do not think that this is the right place about a deeper discussion of OOP concepts in general or related to Objective-C. However, you should know that both concepts have the same root of the same man (Alan Kay, "inventor" of OOP and Smalltalk with similar ideas) and all what you say contradicts that roots. But I'm not willing to write a book in SO comments. Just a pointer for one thing: It is related to constructor inheritance, because the compiler has to define the construction and you automatically in that prison including inheritance for the compiler defined methods.

Comment: Agree, this would be a nice discussion to have while drinking a beer :) I realise Objc has strong roots in Smalltalk, but I also think that Smalltalk is a correct implementation of modern OOP, if for nothing else, it was created in the 70s. Things have changed, concepts have been revised, new papers have been written. I don't know any modern programming language which inherits constructors, I repeat, because it's wrong, with great respect for Alan Kay and his work. Notice that I'm not trying to understand your point of view on this matter, because I already do. I just don't agree.

Comment: `Just a pointer for one thing: It is related to constructor inheritance, because the compiler has to define the construction and you automatically in that prison including inheritance for the compiler defined methods.` Can't understand this.

Comment: What you call "modern OOP" is nothing else than limitations coming from static typing languages or stack allocation. There was no good reason to do so (if static typing and stack allocation is no good reason itself (NO and maybe)), but needs for it.  None of this limitations is caused by OOP itself. However, I finish that discussion now.

Comment: Too bad, I though it was interesting ;) cheers.

Comment: Seems appropriate: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html

Comment: Did you mean `@interface Child : Parent ` ?

Comment: @Dustt yes, I guess so. I'll change

Comment: Can you provide an example where it makes sense to provide a default argument on the subclass and not on the parent class?

Comment: Sure, when using identifiers, for instance. It won't always be the case that the base class knows how to generate a proper identifier if, say, they differ in qualification (domain). However, I don't think that's the worts possible scenario. What if there are no defaults *at all*? Methods such as `init` exist in every class, even if they require some parameters. Objc introduced `NS_UNAVAILABLE`, but it does come with a few catches. Please also check discussion [on Apple's mailing list](http://prod.lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2015/Aug/msg00119.html)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this behavior is fixed in **Xcode 8** (tested in 8.1).

Also I have some notes:

1. To make your `Child` implementation fully finished you should override `initWithWhatever` or make it unavailable. Because `Child` will inherit this initializer from `Parent` of course.
2. If you make `init` unavailable it make sense to make `new` unavailable as well.

So. From now we can fully control our initializers with a help of `NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER` & `NS_UNAVAILABLE` combination in **Objective-C**. It requires more work comparing to **Swift**, but imho it is worth it. Especially if you want to make your class better compatible with Swift.